# How to sort a list of strings "a", "bcd", "ef", and "ghij" in descending order of length?

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

[Paul Graham asked](https://twitter.com/paulg/status/1244921240227282944):

> In your favorite programming language, how do you sort a list of the strings "a", "bcd", "ef", and "ghij" in descending order of length?

One [proposed solution](https://twitter.com/WeatheredMoon/status/1245362909313564678) was:

```
tag_negative_len(Str, NegLen-Str) :-
  atom_length(Str, StrLen),
  NegLen is -1*StrLen.

rem_tag(_-Val, Val).

sort_desc_len(StrLs, Sorted) :-
  maplist(tag_negative_len, StrLs, TaggedLs),
  keysort(TaggedLs, SortedTaggedLs),
  maplist(rem_tag, SortedTaggedLs, Sorted).
```

I assume that the above code was written for ISO Prolog, because it doesn't make use of implementation-specific features. Example usage:

```
?- sort_desc_len(["a", "bcd", "ef", "ghij"], L).
L = ["ghij", "bcd", "ef", "a"].
```

I would have solved it in a similar way. However, the solution is extremely verbose (as compared to the one or two-liners of other programming languages), and pollutes the program with helper/auxiliary predicates. Is there a better way to solve the problem in ISO Prolog?

Comment: In my not so humble opinion, at this level the concept of "verbosity" just amplifies noise (see also: "code golfing") and may degrade legibility to boot. When one is talking about a problem taking several hundred lines, it makes more sense. This is unlike "efficiency" which can be measured as #ops or time(t) or energy(J) even on this little code piece. The key point is that there must be a "flexible enough" sorting function (actually a library problem rather than a language problem) to which you can indicate a sorting order in a "flexible way" (this is a language problem). So it's good.

Comment: This leads to an extension: As in functional programming, perform sort using a "compare function" (possibly defined inline using `library(yall)` and friends) returning -1,0,+1 for every pair of elements.

Comment: How do `["z","a"]` sort?

Comment: @false Does not matter. Either order is fine. Only the length of the string matters.

Answer (score 4):

```erlang
sort_desc_len(L,S) :-
  findall(N-T,(member(T,L),atom_length(T,M),N is -M),LT),
  keysort(LT,ST),
  findall(T,member(_-T,ST),S).
```

that is, findall/3 implements the closures by means of member/2.
setof/3 would allow to merge the first findall and the keysort calls, but it would remove duplicates...

Note that atom_length/2 could not work with an ISO compliant processor. Double quoted strings are lists of codes, not atoms.

Anyway, I agree Prolog is rather verbose when it come to functional programming. I think the cause is that it has a *relational* data model.

Comment: In the spirit of Wadler's "[Theorems for Free](https://ecee.colorado.edu/ecen5533/fall11/reading/free.pdf)" can we conclude (even in the absence of typing) that "`findall/3` (or `bagof/3`) over `member/2`" is actually `maplist/3`?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: I don't think findall+member and maplist are comparable in general, they fulfill very different tasks. For instance, findall can also filter elements, while maplist cannot, but maplist can provide multiple solutions...

Comment: You can always set the `double_quotes` flag to `atom`, which is ISO compliant. Unfortunately, some Prolog systems only support a setting of `codes`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just thinking functionally:

Apparently [predsort](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predsort/3) is the predicate to use. This is actually not ISO, but from [`library(list)`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=builtinlist)

```
my_cmp(X,L,R) :- 
   atom_length(L,Llen),atom_length(R,Rlen),
   ((Llen < Rlen) -> X = '>' ;
    (Llen > Rlen) -> X = '<' ;
    X = '=').

sort_desc_len(L,S) :- predsort(my_cmp,L,S).
```

Depending on how `atom_length/2` is computed (i.e. depending on whether one just needs to retrieve a hidden *length* value rather than traverse the string of the atom), this may be rather fast.

```
:- begin_tests(sort_desc_len).
test(empty)      :- sort_desc_len([],[]).
test(nop)        :- sort_desc_len([aaa,bb,c],[aaa,bb,c]).
test(reverse)    :- sort_desc_len([a,bb,ccc],[ccc,bb,a]).
test(duplicates) :- sort_desc_len([a,bb,bb,ccc],[ccc,bb,a]).
test(stability)  :- sort_desc_len([i,j,k],[i,j,k]).
test(random)     :- sort_desc_len([a,xx,fg,hhh,jk],[hhh,xx,fg,jk,a]).
test(exercise)   :- sort_desc_len([a,bcd,ef,ghij],[ghij,bcd,ef,a]).
:- end_tests(sort_desc_len).
```

So, I Herd U Liek Tests...

```
?- run_tests(sort_desc_len).
% PL-Unit: sort_desc_len ....
ERROR: user://4:87:
        test stability: failed

ERROR: user://4:88:
        test random: failed

. done
% 2 tests failed
% 5 tests passed
```

Sadly, `predsort/3` removes duplicates. There absolutely should be a `predsort/4` indicating whether duplicates should be goners or not.

```
?- sort_desc_len([i,j,k],X).
X = [i].

?- sort_desc_len([a,xx,fg,hhh,jk],X).
X = [hhh, xx, a].
```

**FAIL.**

## Addendum

Less noisy using [`compare/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compare/3) as suggested in the comment by *repeat*.

N.B. `compare/3` call with exchanged left and right lengths.

```
my_cmp(X,L,R) :- 
   atom_length(L,Llen),
   atom_length(R,Rlen),
   compare(X,Rlen,Llen).

sort_desc_len(L,S) :- predsort(my_cmp,L,S).
```

```
?- run_tests(sort_desc_len).
% PL-Unit: sort_desc_len ....
ERROR: user://1:20:
        test stability: failed

ERROR: user://1:21:
        test random: failed

. done
% 2 tests failed
% 5 tests passed
false.
```

Comment: If you simplify my_cmp/3 to return just < or > (spare a whole line!) you also avoid to remove duplicates, so a better comparison with mainstream languages (BTW in js you can write L.sort((x,y)=>y.length-x.length) that's hard to beat on shortness.)

Comment: Use `compare/3` instead of  `((Llen < Rlen) -> X = '>' ; (Llen > Rlen) -> X = '<' ; X = '=')`.

Comment: @CapelliC You mean, return '<' (for example) for atoms with the same length? Is there a guarantee that the sort algorithm won't sort forever in that case (because 'aaa' < 'bbb' and 'bbb' < 'aaa' both can be true during processing).

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: in the past I used `(Llen < Rlen -> X = '>' ; X = '<')`. Guess it works...

Comment: @CapelliC That's pretty ninja.

Answer (score 1):

My reply on Twitter to Paul Graham question uses the Logtalk [`list::msort/3`](https://logtalk.org/library/listp_0.html#msort-3) library predicate and a lambda expression calling the ISO Prolog standard predicate [`compare/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compare/3) and the de facto standard [`length/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2) predicate. Assuming the `double_quotes` flag is set to `codes` (the most portable setting; in fact, the only setting some Prolog systems support):

```
| ?- {types(loader)}.
yes

| ?- list::msort(
         [Order, List1, List2]>>(
             length(List1, N1), M1 is -N1,
             length(List2, N2), M2 is -N2,
             compare(Order, M1, M2)
         ),
         ["a", "bcd"",cd", "ef", "ghij"],
         Sorted
     ).
Sorted = [[98,99,100,34,44,99,100],[103,104,105,106],[101,102],[97]]
yes
```

When running on supported backend Prolog compilers that don't provide the `length/2` predicate as a built-in predicate, we can use instead:

```
| ?- {types(loader)}.
yes

| ?- list::msort(
         [Order, List1, List2]>>(
             list::length(List1, N1), M1 is -N1,
             list::length(List2, N2), M2 is -N2,
             compare(Order, M1, M2)
         ),
         ["a", "bcd"",cd", "ef", "ghij"],
         Sorted
     ).
Sorted = [[98,99,100,34,44,99,100],[103,104,105,106],[101,102],[97]]
yes
```

Funny enough, this is one of the most portable solutions provided so far, working on 12 Prolog systems (i.e. in all Logtalk supported systems).

As @CapelliC remarked, a relational language will always provide a more verbose solution compared with a functional language.

Comment: Neat. Also removes the problem of helper predicates floating around in predicate space.